# Sending mail using Ajax call going in loop

Tags: ajax, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send email. It works fine but the below code keeps on running in loop and alert never ends

Here is my code

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"send.php",
        data:data, 
        success: function(result) {
          alert("hi"+result);
          window.location = 'index.html';
      },
      error: function(result) {
          alert("h0"+ result);
      }

  });

      return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If that’s really all your code, and it’s in `index.html`, it will run when the page loads, send the email, then redirect to itself, where the process will start again, and so on, forever.

Probably the easiest way to fix this is simply delete the `window.location` line, then it will send the email and stop.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using die(); before return false